# Pricing American Stock Option with TensorFlow Neural Network , Simulate by Monte Carlo

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, montecarlo, stock

so what I try to do is to simulate with Monte Carlo a American Option (Stock) and use TensorFlow to price it.

I use two helper function , **get_continuation_function** to create the TF operators. And the **pricing_function** to create the computational graph for the pricing.

The **npv** operator is sum of the optimal exercise decisions. At each time I check if the exercise value is greater than the predicted continuation value (in other words, whether the option is in the money).

And the actual pricing function is **american_tf**. I execute the function to create the paths, the exercise values for the training path. Then, I iterate backward through the training_functions and learn the value and decision on each exercise date.

```
def get_continuation_function():
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,1),name="X")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,1),name="y")
    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((1,1))*0.1,,name="w")
    b = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.ones(1)*1,name="b")
    y_hat = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w), b)
    pre_error = tf.pow(y-y_hat,2)
    error = tf.reduce_mean(pre_error)
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(error)
    return(X, y, train, w, b, y_hat)


def pricing_function(number_call_dates):
    S = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="S")
    # First excerise date
    dts = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="dts")
    # 2nd exersice date
    K = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="K")
    r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,,name="r")
    sigma = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="sigma")
    dW = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="dW") 

    S_t = S * tf.cumprod(tf.exp((r-sigma**2/2) * dts + sigma * tf.sqrt(dts) * dW), axis=1)
    E_t = tf.exp(-r * tf.cumsum(dts)) * tf.maximum(K-S_t, 0)

    continuationValues = []
    training_functions = []

    previous_exersies = 0
    npv = 0
    for i in range(number_call_dates-1):
        (input_x, input_y, train, w, b, y_hat) = get_continuation_function()
        training_functions.append((input_x, input_y, train, w, b, y_hat))
        X = tf.keras.activations.relu(S_t[:, i])
        contValue = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w),b)
        continuationValues.append(contValue)
        inMoney = tf.cast(tf.greater(E_t[:,i], 0.), tf.float32)
        exercise = tf.cast(tf.greater(E_t[:,i], contValue[:,0]), tf.float32) * inMoney * (1-previous_exersies)
        previous_exersies += exercise
        npv += exercise*E_t[:,i]

    # Last exercise date
    inMoney = tf.cast(tf.greater(E_t[:,-1], 0.), tf.float32)
    exercise =  inMoney * (1-previous_exersies)
    npv += exercise*E_t[:,-1]
    npv = tf.reduce_mean(npv)
    return([S, dts, K, r, sigma,dW, S_t, E_t, npv, training_functions])


def american_tf(S_0, strike, M, impliedvol, riskfree_r, random_train, random_pricing):
    n_exercise = len(M)
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        S,dts,K,r,sigma,dW,S_t,E_t,npv,training_functions = pricing_function(n_exercise)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        paths, exercise_values = sess.run([S_t,E_t], {
            S: S_0,
            dts: M,
            K: strike,
            r: riskfree_r,
            sigma: impliedvol,
            dW: random_train
        })

        for i in range(n_exercise-1)[::-1]:
            (input_x,input_y,train,w,b,y_hat) = training_functions[i]
            y= exercise_values[:,i+1:i+2]
            X = paths[:,i]
            print(input_x.shape)
            print((exercise_values[:,i]>0).shape)
            for epochs in range(100):
                _ = sess.run(train, {input_x:X[exercise_values[:,i]>0], 
                                     input_y:y[exercise_values[:,i]>0]})
                cont_value = sess.run(y_hat, {input_x:X, input_y:y})   
                exercise_values[:,i+1:i+2] = np.maximum(exercise_values[:,i+1:i+2], cont_value)

        npv = sess.run(npv, {S: S_0, K: strike, r: riskfree_r, sigma: impliedvol, dW: N_pricing})

        return npv


N_samples_learn = 1000
N_samples_pricing = 1000
calldates = 12
N = np.random.randn(N_samples_learn,calldates)
N_pricing = np.random.randn(N_samples_pricing,calldates)

american_tf(100., 90., [1.]*calldates, 0.25, 0.05, N, N_pricing)
```

Calldates is the number of steps
training sample set = 1000
test sample size = 1000

But my error is very weird

```
 ---> 23                 nput_y:y[exercise_values[:,i]>0]})

 ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (358,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_441:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

Comment: Hi, @hallo12! May be I've missed something, but what's `M`? What does it mean and what data it contains? Please, provide an example of the data provided to `M` - otherwise this code is not runnable and hard to understand

Comment: Sorry, M is the TimeStep  from the stock  .. in this case M=[1.,1.,1. ,1.,1.,1. ,1.,1.,1. ,1.,1.,1.].

Comment: That just means you need to reshape your "input_x:X[exercise_values[:,i]>0]" to have a shape of (358,1)

Comment: thanks :) . Why input_x and not input_y ? and otherwise is the code okay ,for pricing american put options ?

Comment: @Tim probably reshape to (?, 1), not (some number, 1), because first dimension can be different

Comment: @hallo12 you probably need to reshape input_y in this case as well. The rest looks good. But for a fast prototype, I would use "keras" package as the neural network stuff is already done, especially if it's simple like in this case (1 hidden layer, 1 neuron, relu activation, adam optimizer).

Comment: @hallo12 what Mikhail means is reshaping by the length instead of specifying a fixed number like "X[exercise_values[:,i]>0].reshape(len(X[exercise_values[:,i]>0]), 1)"

Comment: @Tim I did it and I reshape cont_value=sess.run(y_hat,{input_x:X.reshape(len(X),1) .... in this way but now I get the error       ---> 28         npv = sess.run(npv, {S:S_0,K:strike,r:riskfree_r,sigma:impliedvol,dW:N_pricing}).                                                         InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_696' with dtype float
  [[Node: Placeholder_696 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Comment: @Tim and before I reshaped cont_value , I got this error :..............................---> 24                 cont_value = sess.run(y_hat, {input_x:X, input_y:y}).....................ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_749:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Comment: @hallo12 reshaping cont_value is right. For easier debugging, can you give names to the placeholders? For example, "S = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='S')" so we know exactly which placeholder is give you the issue.

Comment: @hallo12 I think the issue may be that you missed "dts:M" in the last "sess.run(npy, ...)"

Comment: @Tim.                  I gave them names u can see it in my origin code and did dts:M Now I got this :       23                                      input_y:y[exercise_values[:,i]>0].reshape(len(y[exercise_values[:,i]>0]),1)})...............ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (351, 1) for Tensor 'X_43:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'

Comment: @hallo12 that's pretty strange as "X" should have shape (?,1), it's possible adding name messed it up. you can try removing the names.

Comment: @Tim I saw my mistake. But now I got this error : ----> 1 american_tf(100.,90.,[1.]*calldates,0.25,0.05,N,N_pricing).............---> 28         npv = sess.run(npv, {S:S_0,K:strike,dts:M,r:riskfree_r,sigma:impliedvol,dW:N_pricing})...........................................InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix
  [[Node: MatMul_611 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Relu_241, w_65/read)]].         Thank u a lot Tim ,u save my life :)

Comment: @hallo12 that might be my fault, I edited the code in your question. You had M=[], I thought that was incorrect so I edited it to M=[1.]*calldates in the last line. Maybe that broke the code.

Comment: @Tim nope. There Is something else. Maybe something is wrong with my X

Comment: @hallo12 So you want X as [1000,1] tensor, to do that you need "X = tf.keras.activations.relu(S_t[:, i:i+1])". By changing [:,i] to [:,i:i+1], the shape changes from [1000] to [1000,1].

Comment: @Tim wow thank u sooo much . It works :) The Value is a little bit too high  but it works haha

Comment: @hallo12 congrats! now you can finetune the network, may add more nodes or layers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things discussed in comment with @hallo12. I just want to upload a working version incorporating all the changes. The code is tested and runs without error. But to make sure the final training output is correct, you may want to compare against some benchmark.

**General comment**: It's good to separate the variable and time dimension in this type of application, especially when you only have 1 variable. For example, your input array should be 3D with

```
[time, training sample, input variable]
```

rather than 2D with [training sample, time]. This way when you iterate over the time dimension, the rest of the dimensions are kept unchanged.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def get_continuation_function():
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,1),name="X")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,1),name="y")
    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((1,1))*0.1,name="w")
    b = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.ones(1)*1,name="b")
    y_hat = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w), b)
    pre_error = tf.pow(y-y_hat,2)
    error = tf.reduce_mean(pre_error)
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(error)
    return(X, y, train, w, b, y_hat)


def pricing_function(number_call_dates):
    S = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="S")
    # First excerise date
    dts = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="dts")
    # 2nd exersice date
    K = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="K")
    r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="r")
    sigma = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="sigma")
    dW = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="dW")

    S_t = S * tf.cumprod(tf.exp((r-sigma**2/2) * dts + sigma * tf.sqrt(dts) * dW), axis=1)
    E_t = tf.exp(-r * tf.cumsum(dts)) * tf.maximum(K-S_t, 0)

    continuationValues = []
    training_functions = []

    previous_exersies = 0
    npv = 0
    for i in range(number_call_dates-1):
        (input_x, input_y, train, w, b, y_hat) = get_continuation_function()
        training_functions.append((input_x, input_y, train, w, b, y_hat))
        X = tf.keras.activations.relu(S_t[:, i:i+1])
        contValue = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w),b)
        continuationValues.append(contValue)
        inMoney = tf.cast(tf.greater(E_t[:,i], 0.), tf.float32)
        exercise = tf.cast(tf.greater(E_t[:,i], contValue[:,0]), tf.float32) * inMoney * (1-previous_exersies)
        previous_exersies += exercise
        npv += exercise*E_t[:,i]

    # Last exercise date
    inMoney = tf.cast(tf.greater(E_t[:,-1], 0.), tf.float32)
    exercise =  inMoney * (1-previous_exersies)
    npv += exercise*E_t[:,-1]
    npv = tf.reduce_mean(npv)
    return([S, dts, K, r, sigma,dW, S_t, E_t, npv, training_functions])


def american_tf(S_0, strike, M, impliedvol, riskfree_r, random_train, random_pricing):
    n_exercise = len(M)
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        S,dts,K,r,sigma,dW,S_t,E_t,npv,training_functions = pricing_function(n_exercise)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        paths, exercise_values = sess.run([S_t,E_t], {
            S: S_0,
            dts: M,
            K: strike,
            r: riskfree_r,
            sigma: impliedvol,
            dW: random_train
        })

        for i in range(n_exercise-1)[::-1]:
            (input_x,input_y,train,w,b,y_hat) = training_functions[i]
            y= exercise_values[:,i+1:i+2]
            X = paths[:,i]
            print(input_x.shape)
            print((exercise_values[:,i]>0).shape)
            for epochs in range(100):
                _ = sess.run(train, {input_x:(X[exercise_values[:,i]>0]).reshape(len(X[exercise_values[:,i]>0]),1),
                                     input_y:(y[exercise_values[:,i]>0]).reshape(len(y[exercise_values[:,i]>0]),1)})
                cont_value = sess.run(y_hat, {input_x:X.reshape(len(X),1), input_y:y.reshape(len(y),1)})
                exercise_values[:,i+1:i+2] = np.maximum(exercise_values[:,i+1:i+2], cont_value)

        npv = sess.run(npv, {S: S_0, K: strike, dts:M, r: riskfree_r, sigma: impliedvol, dW: N_pricing})

        return npv


N_samples_learn = 1000
N_samples_pricing = 1000
calldates = 12
N = np.random.randn(N_samples_learn,calldates)
N_pricing = np.random.randn(N_samples_pricing,calldates)

print(american_tf(100., 90., [1.]*calldates, 0.25, 0.05, N, N_pricing))
```